# Objective-C class method local variables of type "self"

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-typing

We're all familiar with the following pattern for instantiating instances of a class:

```
+ (instancetype)createInstance {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
```

This works because "self" in this case refers to the class rather than an object built from the class blueprint.

We also know this declaration, most commonly used in avoiding retain cycles:

```
typeof(self) someStrongSelf = self;
```

This is allows `self`'s type to be dynamic and that code could be copy-pasted wherever needed no matter the class.

My question deals with combining the above two patterns when instantiating from a class method:

```
+ (instancetype)createInstance:(MyObject*)dependency {
    typeof(self) instance = [[self alloc] init];
    instance.dependency = dependency;

    return instance;
}
```

This won't work because `self` is a class, and a `typeof(class)` is just a `Class`, but is there some mechanism for local variables equivalent to `instancetype` that would allow me the same flexibility as typeof(instance)? For example:

```
+ (instancetype)createInstance:(MyObject*)dependency {
    instanceof(self) instance = [[self alloc] init]; //desired keyword
    instance.dependency = dependency;

    return instance;
}
```

If I really wanted this formalized, I know an alternative to this would be defining a protocol that does basically the same thing as above, but I'm curious if Objective-C allows the desired declaration style out of the box.

Comment: I agree with @Rob. Not sure why you're trying to keep it so generic. `TheClass *instance = [[TheClass alloc] init]; instance.dependency = dependency;`

Comment: I'll admit there's not much of a practical reason for my question. I just find myself strongly typing a call to `[[self alloc] init]` so often that I was curious if I overlooked a keyword. But I suppose that would've come up in any SO question related to Objective-C before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're looking for, but there is no `instanceof(self)` pattern. The following achieves what you want, though admittedly doesn't have the elegance of `typeof(self)` pattern:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *string;
@end

@implementation Foo
+ (instancetype)fooWithString:(NSString *)string {
    Foo *foo = [[self alloc] init];
    foo.string = string;
    return foo;
}
@end

@interface Foobar: Foo
// perhaps some more properties here
@end

@implementation Foobar
// and perhaps some more methods here
@end
```

This implementation demonstrates that the convenience method still allows subclassing. I.e., you can do:

```
Foobar *foobar = [Foobar fooWithString:@"baz"];
```

And the resulting object will be a `Foobar` instance.

Comment: Yeah that's typically the pattern I follow. Disappointing that there's not a complementary keyword to `self` from a class perspective, but what can you do?